# Add comment to specific position in xml by code C#

Tags: c#, xml

I know I can use XElement to generate a XML,

such as

```
XElement xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child3", 3),
    new XElement("Child4", 4),
    new XElement("Child5", 5),
);

Console.WriteLine(xmlTree2);
```

the result is

```
<Root>
  <Child3>3</Child3>
  <Child4>4</Child4>
  <Child5>5</Child5>
</Root>
```

.

**And my question is, is there some way to add coment to specific position in xml by code use C#?**

.

What I want to do is like

```
XElement xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child3", 3),
    new XElement("Child4", 4),

    //Maybe Some Way to Add Comment Like This
    new COMMENT(String.Format("This is a comment test!!!!")),  

    new XElement("Child5", 5),
);

Console.WriteLine(xmlTree2);
```

and the result is

```
<Root>
  <Child3>3</Child3>
  <Child4>4</Child4>
   <!-- This is a comment test!!!! -->      
  <Child5>5</Child5>
</Root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is as simple as using `XComment`:

```
XElement xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child3", 3),
    new XElement("Child4", 4),

    //Maybe Some Way to Add Comment Like This
    new XComment(String.Format("This is a comment test!!!!")),  

    new XElement("Child5", 5),
);
```

Comment: I test and Success, You're Right, first time of me to know the XComment class, thanks!  I can mark it as accept after 6 mins